# Ito's lemma - mistake in text book?

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-calculus

Ito gives us $$dW = \dfrac{dW}{dX} dX + \left(\frac{dW}{dt} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2W}{dX^2}\right) \, dt$$

We have a function $W(t) = 1 + t + E^{X(t)}$. My text book says that $$dW = e^{X(t)} \, dX + (1+e^{X(t)}) \, dt$$

Am I correct in asserting that the factor $\dfrac{1}{2}$ has been forgotten in front of the second $e^{X(t)}$?

Comment: Yes, provided $\langle X\rangle_t=t$. And one can recommend to make a distinction between the process $W$ such that $W_t=1+t+e^{X_t}$ and the function $G$ such that $W_t=G(t,X_t)$, here $G:(t,x)\mapsto1+t+e^x$. Itô's formula is most easily written down using the latter, as $$dW_t=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(t,X_t)dX_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t,X_t)dt+\frac12\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}(t,X_t)d\langle X\rangle_t.$$

Comment: @Did I would post this as answer, there's not so much to add